# send curl stdout and stderr to a grep

Tags: bash, curl, stdout

I need to grep both stdout and stderr curl output.

When I do it the naive way I get this errror::

```
  $ curl -g 'localhost:9200/dt/cc/_mapping?pretty' &> | grep type
  bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
  $
```

So for now I do it this way::

```
  $ curl -g 'localhost:9200/dt/cc/_mapping?pretty' &> a; grep type a; rm a
            "type" : "text",
                "type" : "keyword",
            "type" : "long"
            "type" : "text",
                "type" : "keyword",
  $
```

What is the correct way to do that?

*Sorry for the duplicate.*

for `>=bash-4` answer is::

```
$ curl -g 'localhost:9200/dt/cc/_mapping?pretty' |& grep type
     "type" : "text",
     ...
```